# Multiple domains with Traefik

Tags: traefik

I am new to Traefik but trying to migrate from jwilder/nginx-proxy and letsencrypt-companion to Traefik.
I have setup Traefik with this config file:
`traefik.yml`

```
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: websecure
          scheme: https    
  websecure:
    address: :443

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

certificatesResolvers:
  le:
    acme:
      email: username@gmail.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        # used during the challenge
        entryPoint: web

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    exposedByDefault: false
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /data/disk1/traefik/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml
      - /data/disk1/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik
```

When starting one container on domain #1

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  confluence:
    container_name: confluence
    image: atlassian/confluence-server:7.6.2
    volumes:
      - /data/disk1/atlassian/application-data/confluence:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    external_links:
      - postgres:postgres
    environment:
      - CATALINA_CONNECTOR_PROXYNAME=confluence.tld
      - CATALINA_CONNECTOR_PROXYPORT=443
      - CATALINA_CONNECTOR_SCHEME=https
      - CATALINA_CONNECTOR_SECURE=true
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=confluence.tld
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=web
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8090
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=user@tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=confluence.tld
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.confluence.rule=Host(`confluence.tld`)
      - traefik.http.routers.confluence.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.confluence.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.confluence.service=confluence
      - traefik.http.services.confluence.loadbalancer.server.port=8090
    networks:
      - web
    restart: always
networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: web
```

It works perfect.
**NOTE:** I have kept the environment variables for jwilder/nginx-proxy for the time being
When launching another container with different tld I can't get that working.

E.g.
`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  confluence:
    container_name: myapp
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - /data/disk1/myapp/www/:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
      - /data/disk1/myapp/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - "9999:80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.tld2,tld2
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=web
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=9999
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=user@tld2
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=www.tld2,tld2
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.myapp.rule=Host(`tld2`) || Host(`www.tld2`)
      - traefik.http.routers.myapp.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.myapp.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.myapp.service=tld2
      - traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.server.port=9999
    networks:
      - web
    restart: always
networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: web
```

It doesn't work but everything looks OK in Traefik dashboard.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in the second `docker-compose.yml`:

You define the router named `mypp` to use a service named `tld2`:

`traefik.http.routers.myapp.service=tld2`

but your service is named `myapp`:

`traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.server.port=9999`

This should have generated an error in Traefik's log regarding an unresolvable service.

To fix this, configure your router `myapp` to use the service `myapp`:

`traefik.http.routers.myapp.service=myapp`

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution at https://community.traefik.io/t/traefik-routing-to-two-different-domains/7316